# Idea solve a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

can you give me the idea to solve this system,
$$
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{}
\log_y(x)+\log_x(y)=\frac{5}{2}\\
xy=27
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}$$

Comment: Have you tried to change the basis of logarithm to same?

Answer (score 3):

$\log_x y$ and $\log_y x$ are reciprocals of each other, so you have
$$
u + \frac 1 u = \frac 5 2.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $u$ yields
$$
u^2 + 1 = \frac 5 2 u
$$
or, if you like,
$$
2u^2 + 2 = 5u.
$$
So $\log_x y = 2$ and $\log_y x = \frac 1 2;$ and so $x^2 = y.$

Now you have
\begin{align}
& x^2 = y, \\
& xy = 27.
\end{align}
From this you get $x^3 = 27.$

Answer (score 2):

Using that $$\log_{x}{y}=\frac{1}{\log_{x}{y}}$$ we get
$$1+\frac{1}{(\log_{x}{y})}=\frac{5}{2}\log_{x}{y}$$ substituting $t=\log_{x}{y}$ you have a quadratic equation.
$$1+t=\frac{5}{2}t^2$$

Comment: It was a typo, just corrected.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is as follows:

- We can write $\log_x y = \frac{\log_b y}{\log_b x}$ with any base $b>0, b\neq 1$.
- Since $xy=27=3^3$, you may choose $b= 3$.
- Besides this you can take the logarithm of the second equation. So, you get the system
  $$\log_3 (xy) = \log_3 x + \log_3 y = 3, \frac{\log_3 x}{\log_3 y} + \frac{\log_3 y}{\log_3 x} = \frac{5}{2}$$

Now, just substitute $\log_3 y= 3 - \log_3 x$ in the other equation and solve for $\log_3 x$. After some rearranging you get

$$\log_3^2 x - 3 \log_3 x + 2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow (\log_3 x -1)(\log_3 x -2) = 0$$

Since $\log_3 x =1 \Leftrightarrow x=3$ and $\log_3 x =2 \Leftrightarrow x=9$, the solutions are $x=3, y=9$ and $x=9,y=3$.